# I cannot get split to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Here is the code for the program that I have done so far.  I am trying to calculate the efficiency of NBA players for a class project.  When I run the program on a comma-delimited file that contains all the stats, instead of splitting on each comma it is creating a list entry of the entire line of the stat file.  I get an index out of range error or it treats each character as a index point instead of the separate fields.  I am new to this but it seems it should be creating a list for each line in the file that is separated by elements of that list, so I get a list of lists.  I hope I have made myself understood.

Here is the code:

```
def get_data_list (file_name):
    data_file = open(file_name, "r")
    data_list = []
    for line_str in data_file:

        # strip end-of-line, split on commas, and append items to list
        line_str.strip()       
        line_str.split(',')

        print(line_str)

        data_list.append(line_str)
        print(data_list)                






file_name1 = input("File name: ")
result_list = get_data_list (file_name1)


print(result_list)
```

I do not see how to post the data file for you to look at and try it with, but any file of numbers that are comma-delimited should work.

If there is a way to post the data file or email to you for you to help me with it I would be happy to do so.

Boliver

Comment: By the way I am using Python 3.3

Comment: You might want to look into using the csv module, it will handle the column splitting for you.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable objects, this means you can't change them in place. That means, any operation on a string returns a new one. Now look at your code:

```
line_str.strip()            # returns a string      
line_str.split(',')         # returns a list of strings
data_list.append(line_str)  # appends original 'line_str' (i.e. the entire line)
```

You could solve this by:

```
stripped = line_str.strip()
data = stripped.split(',')
data_list.append(data)
```

Or concatenating the string operations:

```
data = line_str.strip().split(',')
data_list.append(data)
```

Comment: I got the split to work now I get the following error message:

Comment: I now get a list index out of range error message.  I have verified the index of the various data fields in the list as elements 7 to 23 and that is what my code calls for.  I would post the code for the calculation but it will not format correctly and I cannot post an answer to my own question yet.

Comment: Can't really help without seeing the code... Why will it not format correctly? Did you try to edit your answer and append the code? Otherwise you could create a new question.